# iOS firework explosion using Sprite Kit particles

Tags: iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm implementing app for kids activities and I want to add celebration animation such a fireworks:

[image]

any of you knows this be implemented using Sprite Kit particles or if is another option please let me know.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: I can't help here but have you seen http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Particle_Emitter_Tutorial?

Comment: I'm trying to make confetti, with all varying colours. Has anybody managed to make this work in SpriteKit?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can easily be done using the Particle Emitter Editor, which I advise you to read about [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-particle_emitter/Introduction/Introduction.html).

---

Here's my set up to get a similar effect:

1. first off we need to create a SpriteKite Particle File

**right click project -> new file - > SpriteKit Particle File**
[image]

2. Next select **Particle Template -> Spark**
3. To load this file use this (objective-c):

   SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyParticle" ofType:@"sks"]];

Now to do complex things like remove from sky, you'll have to change the life time of the emitter. Again read the Apple docs.

---

For those who keep coming back to this question (and then down voted it because I didn't show you what my side bar configurations looked like) here's an example of what could be your firework set up.

[image: SpriteKit Firework example]

Here's an example of what it looks like in action (with the above config):

[image]

Comment: Not going to say that the particles can't create an interesting effect, but there is a bit more to creating a display as seen above in the image in the question than `SKEmitterNode` supports. Was kind of bummed out when I ran into the limitations. For example node spawning angles are random in a range. What if you wanted to have a firework where 10 particles flew out of center at spaced angles to create a proper flower type firework.

Comment: Not to mention that to create a proper streaking effect as above, you'd have to use an emitter node for each individual streak. Having multiple emitter nodes kills performance very quickly. Yes, I did spend some time trying to create proper fireworks with `SKEmitterNode`. Ultimately found that it's not the way to create the effect in the image above. If I get some time later this week, I'll post a brief summary of what I did. But, a much simpler fireworks effect, sure, `SKEmitterNode` is viable.

Comment: Hi, did you post the brief summary of what you did to get the fireworks effect?

Comment: You need to try edit each generated `SKEmitterNode` manually, but I don't figure it out yet. Look this link, probably will give u some idea:
[spritekit-snippets](https://github.com/ccabanero/ios-spritekit-snippets)

Comment: Thanks, detailed answer v helpful  to those new to sprite kit , Ive found playing with the Color Ramp helps